# (Quasi)-coherence of the weight $\theta$-sheaf

Tags: coherent-sheaves

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.01057), the author defined the weight $\theta$-sheaf as follows: Let $A^{k}_{X}$ be the sheaf germs of real smooth $k$ forms on the smooth manifold $X$, we perform a complexification on this sheaf by $A^{k}_{X,\mathbb{C}}$ = $A^{k}_{X}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}_{X}}\mathbb{C}_{X}$ (where $\mathbb{R}_{X}$, $\mathbb{C}_{X}$ are constant sheaves on the manifold $X$). Then a morphism of these sheaves are defined as $d_{\theta}:A^{k}_{X,\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow A^{k+1}_{X,\mathbb{C}}$ such that $d_{\theta}\alpha = d\alpha + \theta\wedge \alpha$ for any $\alpha\in A^{k}_{X,\mathbb{C}}$. The weight $\theta$-sheaf is defined to be the kernel sheaf of the morphism $d_{\theta}:A^{0}_{X,\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow A^{1}_{X,\mathbb{C}}$ that the author denotes as $\mathbb{C}_{X,\theta}$. My question is: Is this sheaf coherent? The sheaf $A^{k}_{X,\mathbb{C}} $ is coherent, then since $\mathbb{C}_{X,\theta}$ is a subsheaf of $A^{0}_{X,\mathbb{C}}$, $\mathbb{C}_{X,\theta}$ being quasi-coherent will  be enough to prove its coherence.
If we consider the smooth manifold $X$ to be a complex manifold as well, then the sheaf  $A^{0}_{X,\mathbb{C}}$ is the structure sheaf (sheaf of germs of holomorphic functions on $X$). Let $U\subset X$ be any open set,
quasi coherence would imply that there should be an exact sequence of the form $(A^{0}_{X,\mathbb{C}}|_U)^{\oplus m} \rightarrow (A^{0}_{X,\mathbb{C}}|_U)^{\oplus n} \rightarrow A^{0}_{X,\mathbb{C}}|_U \rightarrow 0 $. Is this true?
Thanks in advance.